# Eslint-plugin-react configuration docs

Tags: reactjs, eslint, eslintrc

Something in the `eslint-plugin-react` docs isn't clear to me.

https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react

It says I should also specify settings that will be shared across all the plugin rules (picture below).

But it doesn't say where should I add those settings. Should I add it to the `.eslintrc.json` file as a top-level property? Where else could it be?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they mean your project ESLint config that is usually `.eslintrc.json`.

By `settings` they mean the [Shared Settings in the config](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#adding-shared-settings).